# C advice on excepting handlng

Tags: c, error-handling

As I am fairly new to C++, I am having trouble with regards to excepting handling for my school assignment. I have never touched on excepting before.

What I need to do for my assignment is to create an excepting mechanism to calculate how much memory (in MB) can be allocated in a program.

I am supposed to use `new[]` operator and `catch()` and restricted to a use of one variable only.

I have attempted the codes, and this is what I have so far. I do not know if I am on the right track or not. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

```
int main() {

  char *mem;

  unsigned long long count = 1;

  while (1) {
    mem = new char[1025 * 1054];
    if (mem == NULL)
      break;

    free(mem);
    count++;
  }

  std::cout << "count: " << count * 1024000;
}
```

Comment: This isn't related to exceptions, necessarily, but you should always `free()` what you `malloc()`, `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`. Any other mix is bad.

Comment: @alterigel Oh I see. Thanks! How do I implement catch for this case?

Comment: [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) could be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning the *free* is invalid and has unspecified bahavior, the way to delete the allocated memory is `delete [] mem;`

Out of that, it is useless to do *new* then *delete* in your loop, if you want to check the limit allocation size you need to not delete (nor free of course)

If you want to know the max size of a *continuous* block do an initial *malloc* , then *realloc* in a loop increasing the size up to get NULL

For instance

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  void * mem = malloc(0);
  size_t count = 0;

  while ((mem = realloc(mem, (++count)*1024*1024)) != NULL)
    ;

  free(mem);

  std::cout << "count: " << --count << "Mb" << std::endl;
}
```

Note that the program doesn't write in the allocated memory, so I can execute it on my raspberry pi without *killing* it producing a swap :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra a.cc 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
count: 1023Mb
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Using C++ *new* :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  char * mem;
  size_t count = 0;

  try {
    while (true) {
      mem = new char [(++count)*1024*1024];
      delete [] mem;
    }
  }
  catch (std::bad_alloc &) {
  }

  std::cout << "count: " << --count << "Mb" << std::endl;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra a.cc 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
count: 543Mb
```

The result is not the same, it is more realistic and correspond to the free memory I have

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. How would implement catch in this case?

Comment: @coolo there is no exception, just test the result of _malloc_ / _realloc_ is not NULL

Comment: How would I implement a realloc? Not sure how to do it.

Comment: @coolo _realloc_ like _malloc_ is part of the stdlib, also in C

Comment: it's normal that it takes long to run the data right?

Comment: @coolo on my small machine the execution time of my program is 0.025 second, so nothing. Are you sure you get my program ? Your program doing new then delete will never ends at contrario

Comment: it does take very long

Comment: Oh btw, one of my school requirements is to use catch and while(1) loop as well though.

Comment: Yes please. Would appreciate it if u could add in a while loop and catch as well to meet the requirements for my sch.

Comment: @ bruno are u able to add catch as well, or can I follow the answer below?

Comment: Btw, @bruno, just to clarify 1 thing, my sch gave me new char[1024 * 1000]; The 1000 necessary to follow? or change to 1024?

Comment: and thanks a lot for ur help really really appreciate it.

Comment: @coolo a Mb is not 1000*1024 but 1024*1024, this is why I used that. Of course you can anyway change the size and write the number of bytes rather than using Mb as I do, but it will be more difficult ro read ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`void* operator new  ( std::size_t count );` will throw an exception `std::bad_alloc` on failure to allocate memory.

All you have to do is create a function allocate whic calls itself with  smaller memory size on failure; for example you could do something like this :

```
#include <iostream>

void allocate_me(size_t size)
{
    try{
        uint64_t* a = new uint64_t[size] ;
        std::cout << "Size is : " << size << std::endl;
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc &e)
    {
        allocate_me(size-1024);
    }
}

int main()
{
    size_t var = 1024*1024*1024;
    allocate_me(var);
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

Note that the initial memory size and the decrement depends on your system.

Another solution could be to simply look the available RAM - in Linux, you can use `sysinfo` or look into the file `/proc/meminfo` - and start from that point.

Comment: Hi @Clonk, may I know what uint64_t mean?

Comment: oh ok nvm. Googled it.